# Finding the components of the Riemannian tensor given the components of a metric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, curvature

I am looking at a manifold of dimension $n$ (And I am considering a local co-ordinates system $x_1,x_2,\ldots x_n$) and the metric defined by the components $g_{ij} = \frac{\delta_{ij}}{x_1^2}$. I'm wanting to find the components of the corresponding Riemann tensor. This should be a pretty straight forward task but I cannot seem to match my workings to the actual answer.

Of course $g^{ij} = x_1^2\delta^{ij}$ and I have that $R^l_{ijk} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} \Gamma^l_{ik} - \frac{\partial}{\partial x^k} \Gamma^l_{ij} + \Gamma^s_{ik}\Gamma^l_{sj} - \Gamma^s_{ij}\Gamma^l_{sk}$

And I also have derived that $\Gamma^l_{ij} = \frac{1}{2}g^{lm}(g_{im,j}+g_{jk,i}-g_{ij,m})$

So I've done the hard stuff, and it should just be an easy calculation to get the the components of the Riemann tensor. But I can't get my answer to match.

Could someone please help me with the calculations please?

Answer (score 2):

Your metric is conformally flat:
$$g_{ij} =\Omega^2 \delta_{ij}\qquad \Omega := x_1^{-2}$$
and the Riemann tensor of the metric $\delta_{ab}$ vanishes. 
From Eq. (D.7) in Wald's textbook on General relativity (where ${R_{abc}}^d$ is denoted by  ${\tilde{R}_{abc}}^d$, whereas Wald's ${R_{abc}}^d=0$):

$${R_{abc}}^d = -2\delta^d_{[a}\partial_{b]} \ln x_1 + 2\delta^{de}\delta_{c[a}\partial_{b]}\partial_e \ln x_1 + 2(\partial_{[a} \ln x_1)\delta^d_{b]}\partial_c \ln x_1$$
$$- 2(\partial_{[a} \ln x_1)\delta_{b]c}\delta^{df}\partial_f \ln x_1 - 2\delta_{c[a}\delta^d_{b]}\delta^{ef}(\partial_e \ln x_1 )\partial_f \ln x_1 $$
I think that now you can easily complete the computation.
The bracket $[a,b]$ means that you have to anti symmetrise with respect to the indices appearing therein.